# Angular ui.grid. Moving rows between two grids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I recently started to use angular-ui-grid (`http://ui-grid.info/`) and tried to create solution for moving rows between two different grids (exactly this solution but this is done on kendo grid - `http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2qXKy/`).

Since I'm pretty new to java script I failed to recreate this in angular-ui-grid. Have some troubles to assign selected rows of grid1 to grid2 and remove selected rows from grid1.

Does anyone have this solution ready?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I added quick NOT working jsfiddle (`http://jsfiddle.net/LimoJoe/n9h7xmw3/4/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gasomol/edit?html,output) of how you could manage it with two controllers and a service. It's using ngGrid but should still be similar enough to ui.grid in this case.

Not that I think your problems are in how you are setting up the `gridOptions`, in your example I didn't see where you had set the `gridOptions`'s '`selectedItems' property:

See edits:

```
 this.gridOptions = {
     data: 't2.items',
     /** NG Grid way
      selectedItems: [] 
     */
     /** UI Grid way */
     enableRowSelection: true,
     enableSelectAll: true,
     multiSelect: true,
     onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
         $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
         gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(rows) {
             angular.copy(gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows(), ctl.selectedItems);
         });
      }
 };
```

---

Edit:

Based on your comments, [here's a fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnjRvGaAGnQIUk4cGs2W?p=preview) of [the article you referenced](http://javahonk.com/get-selected-rows-angularjs-ng-grid-move-data-another-grid/)'s plunkr which is the upgraded version. Hopefully you can use that as your starting point.

Basically to use ui-grid, starting from that article, [you need to upgrade the version of angular and ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/099_upgrading_from_2).

---

Edit:

Ok, [your JsBin](http://jsbin.com/lineyotece/edit?html,css,output) was really close, I edited it, [here's the new version](http://jsbin.com/tetowe/edit?html,output), now it's an upgraded version of my original JsBin, I think we're there now!

Comment: I was able to do the same with ngGrid, where I used this source (http://javahonk.com/get-selected-rows-angularjs-ng-grid-move-data-another-grid/).
I do have trouble especially with ui-grid, maybe I'm missing something there. 

For selectedItems, I'm setting up $scope.mySelections.
`onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                 $scope.gridApi = gridApi;                 gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(rows){
                    $scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
                 });`

Comment: So for Grid1 I have $scope.mySelections1 with all selected items and for  Grid2 I have $scope.mySelections2. 
So with it I could be able to do the proper adding and removing of selected Items from/to both Grids. Bot not able to do that.

Comment: Thanks Matt, i can have a beer now :) (U2) ... I will add to final version as well batch possibility (once user will select all values, it will update selected list as well)... but you answer my question perfectly ;)

Comment: Enjoy that beer, I'll be doing the same! Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Final solution here [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hugitoxaja/edit?html,css,output) with added callback function `gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch` that user can use Select All button and selected list will be updated.